# How to change navbar border color in Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

In Bootstrap 3 we can change navbar color by setting `.navbar-light` border-color. However, it doesn't working by setting `.navbar-light` border-color in Bootstrap 4.

Comment: are you using the latest beta 4? [here is an example](https://www.bootply.com/mwQ8IEXBhQ)

Comment: <nav class="border border-primary">

Answer (score 8):

Since the OP wanted just the border on the bottom.

```
<nav class="navbar border-bottom border-dark">
   ...
</nav>
```

if you'd like to change the colors or anything else with the borders refer to @klooven's answer.

[Here is the link too](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/borders/#border-color).

Answer (score 6):

```
 <style>
        .navbar
        {
            border:5px solid #000;
        }
      </style>
```

try it

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the border classes in Bootstrap.

Check [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/borders/#border-color) page for the classes.

Eg. class `border-primary`.

Comment: sorry, I mean changing the navbar border color.

Comment: I want to set a custom color and only showing bottom border. adding `border-top-0` `border-right-0` `border-left-0` seems a bit weird.

Comment: Well, that's how it works in Bootstrap. If you don't want to use classes, you can of course just use some CSS.

Comment: If you want to show just the bottom border use `border-bottom` it is the additive solution. The other classes you're using (ex: `border-top-0`) are subtractive.

Answer (score 0):

```
<nav class="navbar border border-dark">
   ...
</nav>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/borders/#border-color